# Adding CompareValidator to dynamically added text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, comparevalidator

I have a form that needs dynamic input boxes that have to be integers. I used a slightly modified version of the code found here to do that: http://www.learning2code.net/Learn/2009/8/12/Adding-Controls-to-an-ASPNET-form-Dynamically.aspx

I have a the following code to add to the placeholder:

```
CompareValidator cmpVal = new CompareValidator();
cmpVal.ID = "cv" + textboxID;
cmpVal.ControlToValidate = textboxID;
DynamicTextBoxIntegerValidation.Controls.Add(cmpVal);
```

Obviously this is missing two very important pieces; the Type and Operator fields. The problem is I can't figure out how to add them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As in your don't know how to use the properties, Type and Operator? I guess I'm not getting a full understanding of whether you know how to use the properties or if its for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type` and `Operator` are simply properties of `CompareValidator`. You can add them as follows:

```
CompareValidator cmpVal = new CompareValidator();
cmpVal.ID = "cv" + textboxID; 
cmpVal.ControlToValidate = textboxID;
cmpVal.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;                //Set your type and operator here.
cmpVal.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.Equal;
DynamicTextBoxIntegerValidation.Controls.Add(cmpVal);
```